# How to clear the command output in C?

Tags: c

I have a C program that monitors terminal size changes with signals and clears the last line every time it changes. Is there a way to clear the output even if it's multiple lines?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int output_lines = 0;

void clear_own_output() {
    while (output_lines > 0) {
        printf("\033[A\033[2K");
        output_lines--;
    }
}

void handle_winch(int sig) {
    clear_own_output();

    struct winsize size;
    ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &size);
    printf("Terminal size changed: Rows = %d, Columns = %d\n", size.ws_row, size.ws_col);
    output_lines++;
}

int main() {
    signal(SIGWINCH, handle_winch);

    printf("Monitoring terminal size changes...\n");
    output_lines++;

    while(1) {
        pause(); // Wait for signals
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It works well, but when the terminal width becomes too narrow and the lines break, it doesn't clear the entire output.

Comment: It might be better to use the `ncurses` library to make this a full-screen application, then you'll have full control over all the lines.

Comment: "clear the output even if it's multiple lines" What do you mean exactly by that? What is "the output" you want to clean, and how do you differentiate it from things you don't want to clean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you were on the right track with the control sequences. The CSI A moves up (default 1) lines. 2K clears the entire line without moving the cursor.

What I did was use the carriage return to return the cursor to the left, then use 0K to clear from the cursor to the end, then move the cursor up 1 line at a time, clearing to the end each time, until the previous string has been erased.

This requires to track what the previous string printed was, and requires the current number of columns (not the number of columns from when the string was printed). To get the string length with variables, you can use sprintf.

These modifications work for my terminal emulator, though it will gobble an extra line if you resize the number of columns to less than 10. Other display stuff breaks a bit when I have that few columns anyway so I think it is just the emulator window causing that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <string.h>
char printline[64];
struct winsize size;
void clear_own_output() {
  /*
  \r     Return cursor to left
  \e[    Escape
  0K     Erase line from cursor to end
  A      Cursor up (1 unit)
  */
  // remove any text on the current line
  // go up one line and remove that text
  printf("\r\e[0K\e[A\e[0K");
  // get the length of what was printed before (minus one)
  int len = strlen(printline)-1;
  // while this is greater than the number of columns
  while (len > size.ws_col) {
    len -= size.ws_col;
    printf("\e[A\e[0K");
  }
}
void handle_winch(int sig) {
  ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &size);
  clear_own_output();
  sprintf(printline, "Terminal size changed: Rows = %d, Columns = %d\n",
          size.ws_row, size.ws_col);
  printf(printline);
}
int main() {
  signal(SIGWINCH, handle_winch);
  ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &size);
  sprintf(printline,"Monitoring terminal size changes...\n");
  printf(printline);
  while(1) {
    pause(); // Wait for signals
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: strlen minus 1 because the last string printed had a newline in it

Comment: the winsize struct could be moved back into handle_winch, the ioctl call could be removed from main, and the unsigned short size.ws_cols could be passed into clear_own_output as an argument